# How obfuscate part of code?

Tags: java, obfuscation, yguard

I try to obfuscate my project, but not all code. I try obfuscate only code from 1 package.
How can i do it in yguard (or somewhere else, proguard?)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html):

> There are three possible ways of specifying which classes will be excluded from the shrinking and obfuscation process:

It looks like the second way will be most useful for you:

> One can specify multiple java classes
>   using a modified version of a
>   patternset. The patternset's includes
>   and excludes element should use java
>   syntax, but the usual wildcards are
>   allowed. Some examples:

```
<class>
        <patternset>
          <include name="com.mycompany.**.*Bean"/>
          <exclude name="com.mycompany.secretpackage.*"/>
          <exclude name="com.mycompany.myapp.SecretBean"/>
        </patternset>
      </class>
```

Comment: thanks!
I tried it, but all of my project classes were empty.

Comment: empty classes and all packages are empty.